# JQuery how to validate file type by getting it's extension using `file.type` function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know you can validate a file type by getting it's extension using `pop`

e.g.

```
var ext = $('#file-input').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
    alert('invalid extension!');
}
```

I also know that you can set an attribute to html input element itself to accept only specific file type.

e.g.

```
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
```

but I've found another way to get the file type

e.g.

```
$('#file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    type = file.type;
});
```

It's only works in newly browser though, I wanted to know on how to validate specific file type with this, for example allow only `pdf`, `jpg`, `docx`, `xlsx`.

I've tried to print in console the output of `file.type` and I get `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` for `docx type` so I tried it like this:

```
if(file !== 'application/docx'){
    alert('Invalid File Type');
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: _"It's only works in newly browser though"_ ?

Comment: is it really necessary for you to use a script to check this? you could do something like `<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />`

Comment: @guest271314 - It's from what I read, it will only works in newly browser. e.g., IE10.

Comment: @Banny That is not accurate. Can you post a link to what you read? Why do you expect the MIME type of a `.docx` file to be something other that what `File.type` is? _".docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"_

Comment: [Office 2007 File Format MIME Types for HTTP Content Streaming](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/) _"Ext: .docx, MIME Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"_

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - yep, it's necessary if you want to learn something new. `I found a new way` .

Comment: @guest271314 - what's with the link?

Comment: I'm searching for it again,  Actually, I only read it somewhere here, one of the answer in question. Let me put link later once I found it.

Comment: That is a the link to a document published by the company that developed the `.docx` extension. Where the MIME types for their "File Format MIME Types" are listed. Why do you believe that the `.docx` extension MIME type is `application/docx`?

Comment: @guest271314 - I know I know ofcourse, what I mean is what is the connection of it to this question?

Comment: The question is based on a false premise.  `File.type` returns the correct MIME type for files having a `.docx` extension. What lead you to believe that the MIME type for a `.docx` extension is `application/docx`?

Comment: @guest271314 - do you mean do I have to really put `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`? instead of `application/docx`?

Comment: @Banny You do not have to do anything. It is not your choice. You did not develop the file format, extension or the MIME type. And you have thus far failed to reference where you encountered a `application/docx` MIME type.

Comment: Well, I'm really confused now.

Comment: can you make it more clear for me?

Comment: There is nothing to be confused about. The company that developed the file format, extension and MIME type for `.docx` lists the MIME type for `.docx` extension as
`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` (see the link to the primary source at this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530032/jquery-how-to-validate-file-type-by-getting-its-extension-using-file-type-fun?noredirect=1#comment95861806_54530032). What is the primary source for `application/docx` being a valid MIME type for `.docx` files? That is the question that you must answer first.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Office 2007 File Format MIME Types for HTTP Content Streaming](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/), published by the company that developed the file format, `.docx` file extension, and MIME type, `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` is the valid MIME type of `.docx` files

```
Ext    MIME Type

.docx  application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

`application/docx` is not listed as a valid [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) for the `.docx` extension by the primary source.

See also [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)

Comment: @Banny As suggested by  Carsten Løvbo Andersen you can use the [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#accept) attribute _"A string that defines the file types the file input should accept."_ at `<input type="file">` element to _suggest_ the file type that the user is able to upload `<input type="file" id="docpicker"
  accept=".doc,.docx,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">`. However, the user can ignore that suggestion. Validate the file at the server. Reliance on client-side validation has issues